# Is prayer to Jesus required for salvation?

Tags: prayer, hell, soteriology

According to the Bible, will those who have heard about Jesus (and, perhaps, even believed that Jesus existed or that he had a special role) and yet have never *prayed* directly to Him (i.e. never addressed Him in prayer by using the name "Jesus") go to hell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an old saying (more or less) in Christianity that it's not a religion, but a relationship.  There is *biblical* support for this coming from this verse:

> [Matthew 7:21-23 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207:21-23&version=NIV)
>    “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven. Many will say to me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name and in your name drive out demons and in your name perform many miracles?’ Then I will tell them plainly, ‘I never knew you. Away from me, you evildoers!’

Very simply, it's not just what about is in our hearts; nor is it about what we do; it's about having the **relationship** with Jesus.

Without prayer, there is no relationship (and can be no relationship).  Without prayer, we cannot make ourselves known to God.

> [Phillipians 4:6 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Phillipians%204:6&version=NIV)
>   Do not be anxious about anything, but in every situation, by prayer and petition, with thanksgiving, present your requests to God.

Phillipians shows that if we do not pray, our requests won't be presented to God and so he will (as stated in Matthew) not know us.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

The Bible tells us of many who were saved prior to the birth of Jesus, so they clearly did not pray to Jesus.

And nowhere does the Bible indicate that the requirements for salvation are different for those who have heard the name of Christ, than for those who haven't.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  I don't think that's a particularly useful distinction, however (thus my answer.)  IOW, I don't think the requirements for salvation change magically once someone hears the name 'Jesus Christ.'  I will clarify my answer, though.

Comment: Did you read my question or just its title? The question is about those "who have heard about Jesus and, perhaps, even believed that Jesus existed or that he had a special role". I believe that hearing things about Jesus greatly adds to a person's accountability before God. Somewhere in the New Testament (citation is needed) Jesus said something like if He didn't testify to the Jews, they would have no condemnation on them, but since He did testify to them and they still had rejected His testimony, they were now without any justification - something like that.

Comment: I agree that hearing things about Jesus greatly adds to a person's accountability. But where to draw the line? If a person has only heard the name "Jesus" in the context of a swear, is that sufficient to be accountable? What if they've only heard that Jesus was a Rabi? What if they read tomes on Jesus, but from an anti-Christian standpoint, and have never heard the true story? My point is, there's either a magic line where someone's knowledge of Christ is sufficient, or there isn't. Since the Bible never says that specific knowledge is necessary for salvation, I believe there is no such line.

Comment: (1) I think that line is already drawn in John 3:16: "For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in Him shall not perish but have eternal life" It is the message that Jesus is the only Son of God given by God to the mankind so that those of the mankind who believe in that Son of God would have eternal life. Of course, neither hearing "Jesus" as a swear, nor merely knowing him as

Comment: (2) a Rabi doesn't convey that message. Other verses where the same line is drawn are these: "But these are written that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by believing you may have life in his name" (John 20:31), "I write these things to you who believe in the name of the Son of God so that you may know that you have eternal life" (1st Johh 5:13)

Comment: @brilliant John 3:16 (and the others) doesn't draw that line. It says "Whoever believes...will have eternal life." It doesn't say the inverse: "Whoever does not believe will not have eternal life."

Comment: @Filmzy - "shall **not perish** but have eternal life"

Comment: @brolliant: You completely missed my point.

Comment: @Filmzy - Why? Where did I miss it? The contraposition "not perish, but have eternal life" definitely means that those who perish will not have eternal life, as well as, those who have eternal life will not perish. Thus, those who do not believe in the Only begotten Son of God will not have eternal life.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. "Those who believe, will not perish."  It says nothing of those who do not believe, except that one possibility is that they will perish. To see what happens to those who do not believe, we must look to other verses.

Comment: A logical analogy would be "Those who follow a map will not get lost, but arrive on time." We cannot assume from this statement that everyone who does not read the map will get lost. There may be other ways to avoid getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

No; arguably the most famous verse in the Bible tells us:

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that
>   whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

<sub>[John 3:16 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%203:16&version=NIVUK)</sub>

It would, however, be rather odd to believe in Jesus and never talk to him. But if someone accepts Jesus as their saviour and then dies suddenly without the opportunity to pray, there's no reason to suspect their salvation is in jeopardy.

Comment: how do you accept him without talking to him?

Comment: @warren it could be a sudden realisation of the Truth, right at the end of (earthly) life. I'm sure it happens.

Comment: @Waggers - (1) But what about Romans 10:9,10,13: "if you confess with your mouth the Lord Jesus and believe in your heart that God has raised Him from the dead, you will be saved. For with the heart one believes unto righteousness, and with the mouth confession is made unto salvation ... for whoever calls on the name of the LORD shall be saved" - It seems to

Comment: @Waggers - (2) say that just faith alone in one's heart is not enough for salvation, a certain immediate proceeding of that faith resulting in a confession or an act of communication to the One in whom you have just believed is, according to those verses, still needed for salvation. Or, better say, a faith that does not result into immediate prayer doesn't seem to be counted as a real faith at all - merely a mental recognition of some facts about the Lord without any attempt to communicate to Him.

Comment: @brilliant what those verses *don't* say is "if you don't confess...you won't be saved". If you believe and confess then you're saved, but John 3:16 says it's the believing bit that's important. We should confess if we have the opportunity - but if we don't, we're still saved. And I would say it's VERY rare for someone to become a Christian and not pray; it's only in very exceptional circumstances that someone would believe without praying. But those circumstances do occur.

Comment: Well, then you still need to prove that "to believe" on John 3:16 doesn't include "to communicate to the One in whom you believe", i.e. could mean only mental recognition of the facts concerning Jesus. I met a lot of people who believe that all that is written in the Gospels is true, however, they are a far cry from wanting to pray to Jesus even once. Also, if only a mental recognition of the facts concerning Jesus is both necessary and sufficient condition, why then Paul didn't say right away "for with the heart one believes unto salvation", but instead went on to talk about confession?

Comment: I disagree. The word "believe" is quite clear, as is its definition. The AV provides this extra sense of the word: "believes in (trusts in, clings to, relies on)". While I would expect anyone who believes in Jesus in that sense would pray to him, that is NOT explicit in that meaning. If you think that the verse has been mistranslated and "believes in" means "prays to" I think the onus is on you to prove that, not on me to disprove it.

Comment: I don't mean "believes in" means "prays to" or that the word was mistranslated, but I mean that in the context of the gospel of John "believes in" may not imply just a mental agreeing with some facts. Context often shapes the meaning of words. You need to prove that here it's not the case. Do you think that those people that I told you about are saved? And also what about Paul?

Comment: I don't mean "believes in" means "prays to" or that the word was mistranslated, but I mean that in the context of the gospel of John "believes in" may not imply just a mental agreeing with some facts. Context often shapes the meaning of words. You need to prove that here it's not the case. Do you think that those people that I told you about are saved? And also what about Paul? (moderators, delete the previous comment - it was from me, but there was something wrong with log-in)

Comment: I haven't implied that there's anything "purely mental" about this sense of belief. The question is whether prayer is necessary for salvation. The sense of "believe" in John 3:16 (trusts in, clings to, relies on) is clearly more than a mental acceptance of facts. Anyone who believes in Jesus in that sense probably *does* pray quite frequently. But if someone chooses to believe in Jesus and then promptly dies without any opportunity to form a prayer, are they saved? That's what the question is asking, and my answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

A very powerful example of someone not needing to pray to Jesus to have salvation and enter the kingdom appears in Luke 23: 41-43.
Three men, two criminals and Jesus were crucified on crosses, side-by-side. One of the two criminals said to the other, in reference to Jesus,

41 "And we indeed (are crucified) justly, for we receive the due reward of our deeds; but this Man (Jesus) has done nothing wrong." 
42) Then he said to Jesus, "Lord, remember me when You come into Your kingdom."
43) And Jesus said to him, "Assuredly, I say to you, today you will be with Me in Paradise."

The criminal Jesus was speaking to wasn't required to pray to Him to receive this promise.

Comment: Since praying is communicating with God, I think that is **exactly** what he *was* doing!

Comment: @new wings - Was the very act of entreating the Lord before his imminent death not an instant of prayer? At least, it was a case, in which someone who trusted Jesus and considered Him as his Lord, was now communicating with Him. This kind of communication is the very essence that constitutes any Christian’s prayer directed to Jesus. So, it seems to me that this episode with the criminal requesting the Lord to remember him in His kingdom only supports the idea of the necessity of praying to Jesus, rather than disproves it.

Comment: I don't believe the disciples prayed to Jesus, however they did have a relationship with him. The question asks does one need to pray to Jesus for salvation. Prior to his sacrifice, the answer would be no. Jesus, himself, taught to pray to "Our Father" in Heaven. However, having an ongoing relationship with Jesus, which can be done through prayer, worship, or simply talking with him throughout your day is comforting and can help keep us walking the path He would have us follow.

Comment: I don't believe the disciples prayed to Jesus, however they did have a relationship with him. The question asks does one need to pray to Jesus for salvation. Prior to his sacrifice, the answer would be no. Jesus, himself, taught to pray to "Our Father" in Heaven. However, having an ongoing relationship with Jesus, which can be done through prayer, worship, or simply talking with him throughout your day is comforting and can help keep us walking the path He would have us follow.